# Is it possible to install two kernels and choose one on startup?

Tags: system-installation, kernel, ubuntu-studio

I want to install Ubuntu Studio and I'm aware that it uses a different Linux kernel than normal Ubuntu. Is it possible to install both kernels and chose which one to use on every startup? And if yes, how do I do that?

I'm not very experienced. Also tell me if there are other more differences between Ubuntu and Ubuntu Studio other than the Linux kernel and the preinstalled software they have. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install both kernels :Generic Ubuntu kernel `linux-generic` and Low Latency Ubuntu Studio kernel `linux-lowlatency`. On boot press <kbd>Shift</kbd>, to get Grub boot menu, then choose advanced.

- If you have installed Ubuntu Studio, install generic kernel:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install linux-generic
  ```
- If you have installed Ubuntu Desktop, then convert it to Ubuntu Studio if you like (skip it if you don't want, you can install just the kernel)

  ```
  sudo apt-get install ubuntustudio-*
  ```

  Install low latency kernal:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install linux-lowlatency
  ```

Comment: mmmmm. I have normal Ubuntu and I don't want to convert my whole system to Ubuntu studio. ...at least not that way. I just want to manually install programs I need and to have Ubuntu studio's kernel so that I'd boot it up when I want to work studio stuff. ...So I just install the kernel by the third command and I'd find it in Grub's advanced options?

Comment: @MinaMichael, yes. that will be ok, just last one

Comment: Awesome! Now I can benefit from Ubuntu Studio without making an extra partition nor Using up disk space! I don't think there's more to Ubuntu Studio other than its programs and its kernel. Thanks!! :D

Answer (score 0):

You can safely install both Ubuntu and Ubuntu studio on the same system but I would not use Ubuntu kernels with Ubuntu studio.

Especially if you're interested in video/audio editing where those studio kernels have specific timings adjustments to fit application needs.

Comment: Thanks but I know I can do that. I'm asking about the kernel!