# Delay while recording piano input

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, audacity, audio-recording

I connected my digital piano to my laptop via a JACK cable and an USB sound card adapter.

After running `pactl load-module module-loopback latency_msec=1` I am able to hear live sounds from piano. Also, I can record them using Audacity.

A major problem that I have is that they are just a little bit delayed. That affects song recording so I cannot follow the song rhythm properly.

Is there any way to fix this problem? Maybe installing low latency kernel? How can I do that?

Comment: If you need more info try searching for rocksmith 2014 cable latency (it's basically a usb sound card) and the topic is popular due to game popularity :)

Comment: @przemo That sounds good also. However, I cannot find a stereo cable. All of them are mono?

Comment: There is no stereo guitar cable, because all guitars are mono. What I meant was that the solution for latency might be similar, because the Rocksmith cable is a usb sound card with one mono mic input.

Comment: Check this out for example: http://www.timelordz.com/blog/2011/12/from-rocksmith-to-free-guitar-effects-and-home-studio-recording/

Comment: @przemo I already have an USB adapter, but the cable that you recommended is still a good choice for my brother, who plays guitar (bass, electric and acoustic). :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- In Audacity preferences "recording" tab,  you will find a latency setting to correct the delayed playing while recording: try to increase both values .
- Best latency is obtained using **Ardour and Jack server**: `sudo  apt-get install ardour` will install both.  No need to change the kernel but the file /etc/security/limits.conf must be edited as root: run    `sudo gedit /etc/security/limits.conf`  in a terminal and add these 3 lines at the end:

  ```
  @audio - rtprio 99
  @audio - memlock unlimited
  @audio - nice -19
  ```

  You must be in the audio group. Check using the `id` command and if needed run `sudo adduser $USER audio` or if you prefer, [install users and group management](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/05/install-users-groups-management-tool-ubuntu1404/)): click **advanced** for your user then  select "use audio device" to be in audio group 
  then reboot .

Running Ardour will auto-launch jack sound server ( temporarily disabling pulseaudio).

In the **session** window, give a project name. In the **audio configuration** tab (see **Note 2**)  set a 256 buffer size for good latency ( higher value for higher latency in case you experience "xruns" (clicks) while recording. You will see corresponding latency in ms: it is good if less than 10ms, very good under 5ms, some modern pc can go under 1 or 2 ms . In **option** tab, verify that **real time** is selected. Click <kbd>start</kbd>.

Then, in the Ardour main window, add a track and click its  "r"record button, and start record from transport bar . It should record fine, if not: have a look at [this Ardour tutorial](http://en.flossmanuals.net/ardour/ch023_recording-audio/).

*Tip: Press **shift+e** to get a mixer strip  for setting track connections  and level as shown in the tutorial.*

**Note**: If no audio is recorded or getting distorded or low level, verify Alsa audio layer capture lauching `alsamixer` in a terminal, or more easily, install and run gnome-alsamixer:

- Set **rec** mode on the relevant fader, generally  **capture** fader
- Set level using the **capture**, **mic**, **mic boost** faders.

**Note2**: "audio configuration" tab in "Session windows" is displayed when you first launch Ardour: it can be used to set jack parameters (buffer, latency, real time). When you rerun ardour, it is not displayed until you kill `jackd` (command: `killall jackd`). But you have the same setting for latency in the **jack** menu in the main Ardour window or in `qjackctl` (another application to control and set jack parameters outside Ardour)

Comment: What do you mean by *You must be in audio group*? I installed that application and went to *User privileges* tab.

Comment: then select "use audio device" to be in audio group and reboot or reopen session.If you are not in, Jack server will complain that it can't get realtime mode. The command `groups` in a terminal displays the groups you belong to.

Comment: `groups` output `audio` that seems to be good. Ardour doesn't record anything (nor piano, nor microphone, just nothing). How can I set it to record the piano and send the piano sounds in my headphones?

Comment: did you add a track and select record on it ? if yes, it is a connection problem : track must be connected to sound card capture (usually automatic in Ardour but..). Press maj + e  to display mixer strip and look here for connecting : http://en.flossmanuals.net/ardour/ch023_recording-audio/

Comment: Finally I managed to get the piano input without any delay. I can record it in Ardour. However, there is a high background noise. The volume of the piano is very low to avoid distorsions. Where can I find the balance how to capture the sounds? I mean, I want piano send a better quality and laptop compute it, removing noise sound.

Comment: Anther issue is that sometimes the sounds is skipping. QJackCtl outputs `XRUN callback (145 skipped)` This is pretty major.

Comment: edited the answer: set level with gnome-alsamixer and increase buffer size (and latency )  to avoid xrun (you can increase from jack menu in ardour): latency lower than 10 or 20 ms is acceptable.Check also realtime mode is on (in session audio option or in qjackctl)

Comment: Thanks. I will try the new settings soon. BTW, if finally I will able to record something properly I will give you more than 25 points of rep. :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16954/discussion-between-ionic-bizu-and-laugeo).

Answer (score 1):

You may try installing:

1. Low latency kernel:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install linux-lowlatency
   ```

   On boot press <kbd>Shift</kbd>, to get Grub boot menu, then choose advanced.

   Similar question: [Is it possible to install two kernels and choose one on startup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/433796/is-it-possible-to-install-two-kernels-and-choose-one-on-startup/)
2. Default Ubuntu Studio settings:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install ubuntustudio-default-settings
   ```

   which contains some audio settings like `lib/udev/rules.d/40-timer-permissions.rules`

   ```
   # make precisian timers accessable to audio group and MIDI
   #
   # created Sep 3 2012

   KERNEL=="rtc0", GROUP="audio"
   KERNEL=="hpet", GROUP="audio"
   ```

   (I haven't tried it)

Comment: I installed it (I remember I did `sudo apt-get install linux-image-lowlatency`) and ` uname -r` outputs: `3.13.0-36-lowlatency `. However, I didn't observe a major difference between them...